# Show that the function $f$ is attain its minimum or maximum value and bounded on $\mathbb R$

Tags: continuity, proof-explanation

> Let the continuous function $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ satisfying 
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{f(x)}=0$$ 
>   Show that the function $f$ is:
>
> (i) bounded;
>
> (ii) attain its minimum or maximum value on $\mathbb R$, that is, there exists a point $x_0\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x_0)$ be the maximum or minimum value on $\mathbb R$.

For the part (i), let 
$$S=\{f(x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$$
Since both $\inf S$ and $\sup S$ are finite, so the function $f$ is bounded.
For the part (ii), I would like to discuss the following four cases:

(a) when $x>M$, $f(x)<\frac{\sup S}{2} \neq 0$ and $f(x)>\frac{\inf S}{2} \neq 0$

(b) when $x<N$, $f(x)<\frac{\sup S}{2} \neq 0$ and $f(x)>\frac{\inf S}{2} \neq 0$

(c) Both $\inf S= \sup S=0$

(d) Either $\inf S=0$ or $\sup S=0$, then the function $f$ either attains its global maximum or global minimum.

How do I elaborate my idea for part (ii) (a) and (b) to show that any local extremum point on the closed interval $[N,M]$ is the global extremum point on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: In part $(i)$ I believe you need to explain why $\inf S$ and $\sup S$ are finite. In part $(ii)$ it's not clear what are $M,N$.

Comment: $M$ and $N$ are both real numbers. I tried to construct a closed interval and show that $f$ has attain its maximum or minimum value on $[M,N]$.

Comment: @weilam06 What bounds do you get from the two limits? Write out the definitions (or one particular case of them), and go from there. You don't need any cases.

Comment: That $\inf S$ and $\sup S$ are finite is basically what you have to show in part (i), so you can't just state it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In part (i), you should elaborate more on why $S$ is bounded. You shouldn't just claim it has a supremum and infimum; you'll need to appeal to continuity (specifically, the extreme value theorem).

In fact, let's show it, because I think it might give you a kickstart towards (ii). Since $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x) = 0$, we know that, choosing $\varepsilon = 1$ arbitrarily, there is some $N, M$ such that
\begin{align*}
x > N &\implies |f(x)| < 1 \\
x < M &\implies |f(x)| < 1
\end{align*}
Consider now the restriction of $f$ to $[M, N]$. Now, $f$ is a continuous function over a compact interval, and thus must be bounded, by the extreme value theorem. That is, there's some $K$ (which is any number larger than the absolute values of the maximum and minimum $f$ over the interval) such that
$$M \le x \le N \implies |f(x)| < K.$$
Now, putting it together, we know that $|f(x)| < \max \{1, K \}$ everywhere, thus showing $S$ is bounded (above and below).

Now, to do (ii), you're right about splitting into cases. First deal with the contant case. Otherwise $\sup f > 0$ or $\inf f < 0$. Deal with these cases separately. Try using the limit definition, this time with $\varepsilon = \frac{\sup f}{2}$ for the first case, and use this to construct an appropriate $M$ and $N$. You're pretty close, you just need a little more rigour.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Suppose $f$ has a non-zero supremum. By definition of supremum, there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) \to M=\sup S$. Note $x_n$ cannot be unbounded, otherwise there is a subsequence of it such that $y_n \to \infty$ and $f(y_n) \to 0=M$.

Then $x_n$ is a bounded sequence, implying that there is a convergent subsequence. By continuity, the limit point is where the supremum is attained.